# Getting transaction hash / ID from the raw data

Tags: transaction-data, development, transaction-hash

Is it possible to get the hash/ID of the transaction having its raw signed hex value only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tx hash is not serialized. Rather it is computed from the tx data. [This answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4217/7493) discusses how the hash is calculated.