# How to get the base transaction hash from the blocktemplate_blob

Tags: ringct, transaction-data, rpc, ring-signatures, transaction-hash

I want to know how to generate different **blockhashing_blobs** using **blocktemplate_blob**, returned by the RPC [get_block_template](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_template) method, with different **extra** fields. To do this, I need  to manually recalculate the transaction merkle tree, and for this, I need to get new base transaction hash. In [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4217/9487) answer, I found that the transaction hash is calculated using **RingCTBase** and **RingCTPrunable**, but I don't find anything about this in the [base transaction structure description](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns003.txt). Can anyone please tell me how to get this data from blocktemplate_blob?

**edited:**
My question is how, having the body of a base transaction, change one of its fields (extra) and calculate the new hash (identifier) of this base transaction. I can't understand where I get the **RingCTBase** and **RingCTPrunable** values. In the description of the structure of the base transaction there is nothing about it.

Comment: Whilst the question is *slightly* different to the one I marked as a duplicate, the [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/6461/7493) covers this question too.

Comment: I didn’t find anything about calculating the hash of the base transaction from raw blob data on this link. Could you please indicate the part that answers my question more precisely? I tried to write it more clearly.

Comment: The answer explicitly explains how the blockhashing_blob is constructed (and more).

Comment: And the base transaction is the same format as any other transaction. And to get its hash, the same as any tx. [source](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5fbfa8a65663e807c6500ae9485e898df9b7c470/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L1053).

Comment: @Oroffe - I marked the question as duplicate. Any questions can still be asked in the comments though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"prefix", "base" and "prunable" just refer to parts in the transaction.

Given the transaction hash is:

```
H(H(prefix) || H(base) || H(prunable))
```

"prefix" refers to [these fields](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5fbfa8a65663e807c6500ae9485e898df9b7c470/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic.h#L172).

"base" refers to the [signatures](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5fbfa8a65663e807c6500ae9485e898df9b7c470/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic.h#L276) that follow the prefix.

"prunable" refers to any [prunable parts](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5fbfa8a65663e807c6500ae9485e898df9b7c470/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic.h#L289) of a transaction.

[Here is the source](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5fbfa8a65663e807c6500ae9485e898df9b7c470/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L1053) that calculates transaction hashes in Monero.

Important to note that "base" referenced above and "RingCTBase" as referenced in your linked answer, do not mean the coinbase/miner transaction. They just refer to a specific part in a transaction.

Now, to *edit* the miner transaction returned in get_block_template, you would need to deserialize the blocktemplate_blob to a block structure, edit the transaction in question, serialize back to a template blob and construct a new hashing blob.

Comment: I experimented a bit with the testnet and found that the RingCTBase in the base transaction always consists of one byte 0x00. Also, when calculating the hash of prunable part, [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5fbfa8a65663e807c6500ae9485e898df9b7c470/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp#L1079) branch is always selected. Do I understand correctly that if I want to calculate the hash of the base tx with the modified extra, I need to recalculate only the hash of the prefix and the final hash of the transaction, while the two remaining ones will always be the same?

Comment: A coinbase transaction doesn't have signatures or prunable data so yes, only the prefix part changes.