# Questions about calculating a transaction ID

Tags: transaction-data

As I know, Transaction ID is calculated from

```
H( H(tx_prefix) || H(tx_stuff) || H(Signatures) )
```

Where

```
tx_prefix = {tx version || keyoffset || keyimage || one-time addresses || extra}
tx_stuff = {signature type || tx fee || pseudo output commitments || ecdhInfo || output commitments}
Signatures = {MLSAGs || range proofs}
```

So I test a example tx: `b43a7ac21e1b60ad748ec905d6e03cf3165e5d8c9e1c61c263d328118c42eaa6`
with MiniNero but failed nevertheless.

```
tx_version = "02"
key_offset = "c8e230afe12f958d49809d0dfaaf33"
key_image = "595a612d0df27181c46a8af70a9bd682f2a000124b873ba5d2b9f4b4e4efd672"

signature_type = "01"
ont_time_addr = "aa9595f55f2cfaed3bd2a67453bb064dc7fd454a09c2418d7338782790185fe30ccb48ed2ebbcaa8e8831111029f3300069cff0d1408acffbfc3810b362ea217"
extra = "02210081464dc2f85d185e0f6be900e552aff37b3acc87ab6465c02abb9da8de62c06e0101b957162674517c5544242ce5eb2e9f8b72ead332291c5c1af9b8e4c5408b05"
txnfee = "8088e2ed60"
ecdhInfo = "68f508c5515694ce5a33b316b990e8b67a944725c93d806767e61b2e0b13d300fbc3e5bdb36fc58e5800ffc549ab7bd533fadb7e6b64898c82ea620d749fc80e913372a2424b22bd9712183f5a7c8027c8d9af89b52d1e7d06fd1f87a1e5d20db9335c3dc0afb774f812f9f58a412c849f3c828d873f1c16ab102963799d9809"
output_commitment = "cf141f5dfe04df14afad6b451d600aa5826a9be44a76a1630850c1d5951d482ee10bb69b66af5dabec765c7f5f7528926088877fa36746833828a0575896ae57"
MLSAG = ""a8120b96f5f2a...611e395a409""
range_proof = "b9b544a75ad5a4df48156aff...16119b7a023303a6752"

L = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(tx_version+key_offset+key_image+ont_time_addr+extra)
M = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(signature_type+txnfee+ecdhInfo+output_commitment)
R = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(MLSAG+range_proof)
result = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(L+M+R)
```

What I get is `60f983800f9791b97368318d21924f8e7ec63012af70db4b45dc831528e28e20`. Not the right transaction id.
Is there any wrong with my thought? Many thanks!

Comment: Your 3 parts (that get hashed to make up the tx hash) are wrong. See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11268/7493

Comment: Mooooo, ZtM2 isn't as accurate as a real spec would be. For exact implementation you'll have to refer to the code itself. In this case function calculate_transaction_hash(). The margin notes of ZtM2 should always (or usually) point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you jtgrassie and koe! BTW, Is there any difference between calculate message and transaction ID? It looks so similar.

Comment: I believe the only broad difference is the tx ID includes MLSAGs, although how they are serialized may differ as well.

Comment: !! But I check the pg51 of ZtM2, It shows m = H(H(tx pref ix), H(ss), H(range proofs)). It changed?

Comment: For the message signed by MLSAGs you'll have to check get_pre_mlsag_hash() https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b4023dcfc5e361be7af6254992699c7cfb090a78/src/ringct/rctSigs.cpp#L411

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you getting your information about the structure of a transaction?

You forgot to include the hex `0001020005`, which consists of the unlock time `00`, the number of real inputs in the transaction `01`, the input type of the first real input `02`, the input amount `00` (0 to indicate it's an encrypted amount), and `05` indicating the number of key offsets that are listed.

You also forgot the hex `020002` which is the number of outputs `02`, the amount of the first output `00`, the type of the first output `02`. Then you're missing the hex `0002` prior to the second output public key, which again indicates the output amount and type.

Then, you've not specified the size of the tx_extra field as `44`. I'm sure there is much more.

Please cross check your work with the C source code, then you'll have a definitive list of things you need to include. At the very least, you should know something is wrong if you're missing out things which you can obviously observe are part of the raw hex of the transaction. The JSON summary of a transaction is not the same as the raw bytes of the transaction, as it excludes things such as the hex of the field lengths and input counts etc.

Comment: This is a bit my fault, pg. 71 of ZtM2 is not extremely accurate (not that I was trying to make a spec to begin with). The function calculate_transaction_hash() is where details can be explored.

Comment: @knaccc, Thanks for your answer! It really helps! However, I tried again with your correction but not succeed yet. Is there an example for calculating transaction ID?

Comment: I can calculate it now! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Mooooo would you mind posting an answer to this question with the complete calculation you made?

Comment: ＠koe I post an answer! If there is anything wrong, please correct me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Also take tx [b43a7ac21e1b60ad748ec905d6e03cf3165e5d8c9e1c61c263d328118c42eaa6](https://moneroblocks.info/search/b43a7ac21e1b60ad748ec905d6e03cf3165e5d8c9e1c61c263d328118c42eaa6) as an example.

We calculate `H( H(prefix) || H(base) || H(prunable) )` for TXID.
Actually, we can divide the transaction into 3 parts perfectly without removing any bit.

The first part `prefix` should be

```
L = "020001020005c8e230afe12f958d49809d0dfaaf33595a612d0df27181c46a8af70a9bd682f2a000124b873ba5d2b9f4b4e4efd672020002aa9595f55f2cfaed3bd2a67453bb064dc7fd454a09c2418d7338782790185fe300020ccb48ed2ebbcaa8e8831111029f3300069cff0d1408acffbfc3810b362ea2174402210081464dc2f85d185e0f6be900e552aff37b3acc87ab6465c02abb9da8de62c06e0101b957162674517c5544242ce5eb2e9f8b72ead332291c5c1af9b8e4c5408b05"
```

which includes components from `version` to `extra`.

The second part `base` should be

```
M = "018088e2ed6068f508c5515694ce5a33b316b990e8b67a944725c93d806767e61b2e0b13d300913372a2424b22bd9712183f5a7c8027c8d9af89b52d1e7d06fd1f87a1e5d20dfbc3e5bdb36fc58e5800ffc549ab7bd533fadb7e6b64898c82ea620d749fc80eb9335c3dc0afb774f812f9f58a412c849f3c828d873f1c16ab102963799d9809cf141f5dfe04df14afad6b451d600aa5826a9be44a76a1630850c1d5951d482ee10bb69b66af5dabec765c7f5f7528926088877fa36746833828a0575896ae57"
```

which includes all components of `rct_signatures`, that is from `type` to `outPK`.

The last part `prunable` is all the rest content.

```
R = "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"
```

Hash them respectively.

```
L1 = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(L)
M1 = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(M)
R1 = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(R)
```

The last step is to concatenate each result and hash again.

```
result = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(L1+M1+R1)
```

The result is the same with TXID

```
b43a7ac21e1b60ad748ec905d6e03cf3165e5d8c9e1c61c263d328118c42eaa6
```

Comment: Interesting, so you just chunk the transaction blob directly into 3 parts and hash them? I suppose it makes a lot of sense.